# Starting location updates

Tags: android, permissions

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationRequest mLocationRequest, this);
    Location OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    String OldLocationTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
}
```

When I type the request for location updates, the location request comes up with "Can't resolve symbol mLocationRequest." However, I have defined it below:

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
}
```

And OldLocation  getLastLocation says the call requires permission, which I have defined in onCreate()

**Does anyone know what's wrong here?**

In addition, I want to find out how to get the location in a location object every few seconds and find out the distance between the two. Many people talk about 'callback objects', but I don't exactly grasp the concept.

**Can anyone help me?**

Comment: seriously? `..(mGoogleApiClient, LocationRequest mLocationRequest, this)` ? `LocationRequest mLocationRequest` as paramater ? what does it mean? do you know java at all?

Comment: Your, `mLocationRequest` has scope only in `createLocationRequest()` method. Declare it outside the method and initialize it inside the method.

Comment: @Selvin Well, not much. That's why I'm asking~. Oh, and the reason I put it there is because the Android Studio tutorial told me so. Check: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: First change this line LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationRequest mLocationRequest, this); to LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

Answer (score 0):

You are passing parameters in wrong way.

Change this line:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationRequest mLocationRequest, this);
```

to

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```